# AngularJS Datepicker date to Unix timestamp

Tags: angularjs, unix-timestamp

```
    var startDateAndTime = $scope.startTime;
    // Mon Mar 28 2016 11:43:54 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
    var startTimeStamp = new Date(startDateAndTime).getTime();
    // 1459161834107
```

BUT, http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php converts that to "12/31/**48208** @ 3:41am (UTC)"

what am I doing wrong? it is obiovusly somethign trivial, but I just can't see it :-(

Comment: The issue is that `` Mon Mar 28 2016 ...` is being converted to a Unix timestamp many millenia in the future

Comment: You should try using some Javascript library for DateTime handling which is cross browser compliant. It seems the problem is with the Javascript Date. You can try http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help (+1), but I don't want to include an extra library just for this. Jquery is alreay included & should handle it, but what is the standard Angular way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php converts the number of **seconds** since 1.1.1970

`Date.getTime()` returns **millis**.

A simple `/1000` would do.

Comment: D'oh! (face plam) <slinks off blushing ...>

Comment: They got me too :)